# How to define multiple run commands for different mainClasses in Gradle's build file

Tags: gradle, command-line, build.gradle

I have an Java project with the following file structure:

```
├── bin
├── build.gradle
├── lib
│   ├── library1.jar
│   ├── library2.jar
│   ├── ...
│   └── library15.jar
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── com
        └── mycompany
            └── myproject
                ├── App1.java
                ├── App2.Java
                ├── ...
                └── App5.Java
```

This project was completely unmanaged (no Maven or Gradle), but I have added a  `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    }

dependencies {
    // Use all libraries provided as jars in teh lib folder
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.mycompany.myproject.App1'
}
```

to compile and run `App1` via the command line:

```
gradle run
```

So far so good.

But how can I now enhance the build file to run the other apps `App2`, `App3`, etc (each with their own `main` function)? Say, for `App2` I would execute something like

```
gradle run --app App2
```

or

```
gradle runApp2
```

How can I define multiple `run` commands or add multiple `mainClass` entries to the build file?

Note: I cannot change the directory structure or the Java code of the roject, because other team members use the project as is without Gradle. So I need to add something to the Gradle build file to enable multiple run tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [@Vamipre on the Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/u/Vampire) I got the [great advice](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/for-the-application-plugin-how-to-add-a-second-run-task-which-targets-another-mainclass/46540) to add the necessary properties to a new task:

```
tasks.register("runApp2", JavaExec) {
    group = ApplicationPlugin.APPLICATION_GROUP
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = 'com.mycompany.myproject.App2'
}
```

Then you can call this as

gradle runApp2

and it does exactly what asked for: Compile and run the project with a main in the `App2` class.